# Is it okay to use python docsctrings for code?

Tags: python

I have developed a python script that will run acceptance tests on a server build.

I used a scheme wherein a generic test function will contain the test name and the test pre-requisites in the docstring. An execute function will parse the docstring on the test function and use the name in the docstring for labeling purposes and the subsequent lines to verify if test dependencies were satisfied (if dependencies failed then no point in running the test).

```
func _test_1(self):
     """
     Name: Test foo
     Test bar
     """
```

I made this work but I am wondering if this is generally acceptable in the python community. **Are there any caveats to using docstrings other than documentation or description of code?**

Comment: On a side note, representing the data using a standardized format like xml or json would make it easier to parse.

Comment: Take a look at the nose test runner.  It has a test generator mechanism that may be an alternative to using the docstring for test information.  Using the test generator would allow you to pass the bits of info you were putting in the docstring as arguments to a check function.  http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html#test-generators

Answer (score 3):

Sure it is; there is even a standard library tool that does this: [`doctest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html):

> The `doctest` module searches for pieces of text that look like interactive Python sessions, and then executes those sessions to verify that they work exactly as shown. There are several common ways to use `doctest`:
>
> - To check that a module’s docstrings are up-to-date by verifying that all interactive examples still work as documented.
> - To perform regression testing by verifying that interactive examples from a test file or a test object work as expected.
> - To write tutorial documentation for a package, liberally illustrated with input-output examples. Depending on whether the examples or the expository text are emphasized, this has the flavor of “literate testing” or “executable documentation”.

Clearly, you hit upon an idea that others thought applicable widely enough to make it a core Python library feature.

Docstrings are *just text*, and you can add any meaning to that text you care to give it. No caveats here!

Comment: Does the OP want to run tests using the docstrings? The example suggests that the docstrings only serve to provide meta information about the tests, which need to be parsed.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik: The OP asks: *just wondering if this is generally acceptable in the python community*. I am illustrating it is a good idea, there are core library modules that do the same thing, e.g. it is a good idea.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: There are also bad ideas in the standard library, but I think this module isn't considered one of those.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Wow didn't realize this is already used in core library modules. Many thanks for the feedback!